# The combination is not working in VS Code and Sublime. How can I fix this?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I tried to comment my code in VS Code, but I can't. I used for this `Ctrl + /`. I was in keyboard shortcats and that combination was there. So, this hotkey is defined.

[image]

Also I want to add that `Ctrl + /` is not working in Sublime as well. It's working only in the Internet (codepen for example). What's my problem? How can I fix this?

Comment: do you have a background program that uses ctrl+/ as a hot key

Comment: @rioV8 Frankly speaking, I don't know. Where can I see that?

Comment: if you don't have VSC running what happens with ctrl+/? You can look at the key binding debugging https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_troubleshooting-keybindings